# Quickly searching within multiple tables for specific data and then referencing a main table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query written for MySQL that's supposed to search within multiple tables for specific pieces of data and then to pull a "ReferenceID" to refer to a master table that has the details about an originating document. I can quickly search for these items just fine, but as soon as I attempt to pull from the master table for the specifics, it appears to just thrash the disk instead of just retrieving the data.

The query I am trying to do looks like this:

```
SELECT ReferenceID as refid, Title as title, Contents as content, TimeSecs as age 
            FROM tabledata u
            WHERE u.ReferenceID IN (SELECT DISTINCT a.ReferenceID as refid FROM table1 a WHERE a.Table1Item = "[item]"
UNION SELECT DISTINCT b.ReferenceID as refid FROM table2 b WHERE b.Table2Item = "[item]"
UNION SELECT DISTINCT c.ReferenceID as refid FROM table3 c WHERE c.Table3Item = "[item]") 
ORDER BY TimeSecs DESC LIMIT 50
```

The SELECT queries within the ReferenceID search could contain multiple OR statements as well, but regardless, a query like this can take upwards of 20-30 seconds even though the query search across the three tables takes maybe a half-second.

Additionally, what makes it more confusing is that it is using filesort to go through the "tabledata" table even though for every other query it's not. Also indices have been created for their appropriate columns and tables.

I did output an explain to demonstrate this:

```
+----+------------------+--------------+----+----------------------+-----------+-------+-----+------+----------------------------+
|id  |select_type       |table         |type|possible_keys         |key        |key_len|ref  |rows  |Extra                       |
+----+------------------+--------------+----+----------------------+-----------+-------+-----+------+----------------------------+
|1   |PRIMARY           |u             |ALL |NULL                  |NULL       |NULL   |NULL |659659|Using where; Using filesort |
|2   |DEPENDENT SUBQUERY|a             |ref |ReferenceID,Table1Item|ReferenceID|98     |func |3     |Using where; Using temporary|
|3   |DEPENDENT UNION   |b             |ref |ReferenceID,Table2Item|Table2Item |386    |const|14    |Using where; Using temporary|
|4   |DEPENDENT UNION   |c             |ref |ReferenceID           |ReferenceID|98     |func |11    |Using where; Using temporary|
|5   |DEPENDENT UNION   |d             |ref |ReferenceID           |ReferenceID|98     |func |7     |Using where; Using temporary|
|NULL|UNION RESULT      |<union2,3,4,5>|ALL |NULL                  |NULL       |NULL   |NULL |NULL  |                            |
+----+------------------+--------------+----+----------------------+-----------+-------+-----+------+----------------------------+
```

Overall I do get the results I desire but not in a timely fashion.

Comment: 1. See JOIN... and dare I ask why you have 3 tables instead of 1?

Comment: Design choice that made sense at the time. They have different types of data that cannot be simply combined with the other.

Comment: I think I'd start with a VIEW of the common data, and take it from there - seems more flexible than GL's solution (if, indeed, that is a solution), but perhaps less efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that you have phrased the query, the SQL engine will probably generate the entire list of reference ids and then start to look in them.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT ReferenceID as refid, Title as title, Contents as content, TimeSecs as age 
FROM tabledata u
WHERE exists (SELECT 1
              FROM table1 a
              WHERE a.Table1Item = "[item]" and u.ReferenceID = a.ReferenceID
             ) or
      exists (SELECT 1
              FROM table2 b
              WHERE b.Table2Item = "[item]" and u.ReferenceID = b.ReferenceID
             ) or
      exists (SELECT 1
              FROM table3 c
              WHERE c.Table3Item = "[item]" and u.ReferenceID = c.ReferenceID
             ) 
ORDER BY TimeSecs DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

Then be sure that you have an index on `ReferenceID, TablexItem` on each of the three tables.

Comment: This looks like the right track but when I test it out it seems to just select everything in the "tabledata" table. Removing the LIMIT appears to confirm that.

Comment: @freak . . . It really should be selecting only `ReferenceID`s that are in one of the three tables where the item matches `"[item]"`.